# Создание читабельной строки из крупного числа (6485251 => "6.485.251")

Tags: c#, строки

Есть потребность выводить на экран крупные числа, но сделать это нужно так, чтобы юзер мог легко воспринимать это число, то есть добавить разделитель между каждыми 3-мя цифрами в числе **Например: (6485251 --> "6.485.251")**.

Как можно реализовать метод, который будет принимать, допустим переменную типа "int" и возвращать "string" с разделителями?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:n}", 6485251 );     //вывод: 6,485,251.00
string.Format("{0:n0}", 6485251);     //вывод: 6.485.251
```

Answer (score 6):

```
        int f = 1234567;
        string s = f.ToString("N3");
```

В таком форматировании разряды будут разделяться пробелами.

Comment: Правильнее сказать, разряды будут разделяться символом, установленным в текущей культуре.

Answer (score 3):

Даешь Linq-монстра! (про эффективность алгоритмов тут нечего говорить, он прекрасен))

```
string ToStringWithSeparator(int num, string separator)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(x =>
        new string(num.ToString()
            .Reverse()
            .Skip(x * 3)
            .Take(3)
            .Reverse()
            .ToArray()))
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
    .Reverse()
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (x, a) => $"{a}{separator}{x}");
}
```

Как проверить

```
Console.WriteLine(ToStringWithSeparator(6485251, " "));
```

Вывод

```
6 485 251
```

Comment: только не "IsNullOrWhiteSpace", а "IsNullOrEmpty", а так спасибо

Comment: @TheFrankyDoll ну это больше ответ-шутка, да и в данном случае не имеет никакой разницы что использовать, работать будет одинаково медленно :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно написать свой метод разделения целых чисел по разрядам, подобный этому.

```
    static string Separate(int number)
    {
        var strList = new List<string>();

        while (number != 0)
        {
            var t = number % 1000;
            number /= 1000;
            strList.Add(t.ToString());
        }

        strList.Reverse();

        // Разделитель задайте сами
        var preparedNumber = String.Join(" ", strList.ToArray());

        return preparedNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Если использовать `Stack`, то не придется делать реверс, и если вместо конкатенации строк использовать `StringBuilder` - то время работы алгоритма уменьшится с квадратичного до линейного :) Ну это просто если вам интересно улучшить вашу функцию.

Comment: @tym32167 А где здесь квадратичное время?

Comment: @Philippe вот тут `String.Join(" ", strList.ToArray());` - конкатенация строк в таком варианте квадратичная

Comment: @Philippe проверил [исходнички](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,fa961ce440526a4d), я извиняюсь, был неправ, таки линейная :)

Comment: @tym32167 Фух, а то что-то я испугался)